# segmentation fault with memcpy (C)

Tags: c, memcpy

I encountered "segmentation fault" error when running the following code, but I am wondering why:

```
int main()
{
char *str = "abcdefghijklmn";
void *str_v;

memcpy(str_v, str, 14);

printf("str_v is %s \n", (char *) str_v);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Declaring a pointer `void *str_v` doesn't automatically make it point somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void *str_v;
```

defines `str_v` to be of type `void *`, i.e., it can store a pointer a variable of any type. However, you need memory space for the characters to be copied by `memcpy` from the source to the destination. Therefore, you need to allocate enough memory using `malloc` -

```
char *str_v = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

`strlen` does not count the terminating null byte in the string pointed to by `str`. Therefore, you have to allocate one extra byte for the terminating null byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // a string literal is read-only so make str
    // const so attempting to change will cause
    // compiler error
    const char *str = "abcdefghijklmn";

    // allocate memory dynamically to the 
    // string pointed to by str. +1 is for the
    // terminating null byte since strlen does 
    // not count the null byte
    char *str_v = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

    // malloc can fail if there is not enough
    // memory to allocate. handle it
    if(str_v == NULL) {
        printf("error in memory allocation\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // copy all bytes in the string pointed to
    // by str to the buffer pointed to str_v.
    // number of bytes to be copied is strlen(str) + 1
    // +1 for copying the terminating byte as well
    memcpy(str_v, str, strlen(str) + 1);

    // print the copied string. It need not be
    // cast to (char *) since str_v is already
    // of type (char *) 
    printf("str_v is %s \n", str_v);

    // free the dynamically allocated space 
    free(str_v);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first allocate memory for `str_v`:

```
void *str_v = malloc(14);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using uninitialized pointer in `memcpy(str_v, str, 14);`, to fix it, you could add the following statements before it:

```
str_v = malloc(14);
if (str_v == NULL) { /* malloc failed */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not allocated any memory for `str_v`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
char * str_v = strdup( str );
```

From http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strdup(const char *s);

The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string
which is a duplicate of the string s. 
Memory for the new string is obtained with malloc(3),
and can be freed with free(3).
```